# Error change JSON to DataTable in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

Error: Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable.Expected StartArray, got StartObject

[image: Exception]

And in Code

[image: Exception while deserializing JSON]

Comment: Could you please post what you are getting in the result from the response?

Comment: From the error you have there, you're receiving a single JObject, while deserializing to a DataTable assumes the data is presented as an Array of objects (your DataRows) that JArray can parse. You can deserialize to a single .Net class object or *hack* the JSON, adding the array boundaries (not really a hack): e.g., `dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)("[" & response & "]")`. Btw, you should **Await** those responses, not use `.Result`.